# Field does not exist error when creating formula field

Tags: formula, formula-field

I have a custom object called Engagement__c that has Account__c. Account__c has a field called Name. The relationship between them is that Account__c is a lookup field in Engagement__c. I want to create a simple formula field in Engagement__c that gets the Name of Account__c.

Account Name (text):

```
Account__c //Works - no syntax error

Account__c.Name //ERROR - Field Account__c does not exist. Please check spelling
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

according to [Understanding Relationship Names, Custom Objects, and Custom Fields](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_relationships_and_custom_objects.htm)

> When you use a relationship name in a query, you must use the
>   relationship names without the __c. Instead, append an __r (underscore
>   underscore r).

so use `Account__r.Name`

Comment: For me, this generates the error "Error: Field Name does not exist. Check spelling." Also, when I use "Insert Field", the field `Name` is not listed, although it very much exists on the lookup object (Lead) and all the other fields are shown as expected. Is there something special about Name?

Comment: @kamezaburo I think, it worth to create another new question